# What is the best way to style a component explicitly?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

How can we add a style explicitly to a component in react. By explicitly I meant that if we are visiting the component the style should be applied and if we are navigating away from that component the style should be removed.

**Scenario 1**
Suppose if we have two components `day` and `night` and the default `background-color` of application is is white. Then if I use\visit the `night` component then the `back-ground` color should change to black and if I navigate away from the night component the background-color should change back to the default

Solution 1

```
//night component
import React from "react";

import './style.css'  //give background-color: black
```

and then import other style sheet that has `background-color: white` property to other components. But this is not ideal as we may end up adding style-sheet to all other components.

Answer (score 0):

You can read [this](https://blog.bitsrc.io/5-ways-to-style-react-components-in-2019-30f1ccc2b5b) for an overview of the several ways you can style react components, but for your specific case, I would recommend using [`Styled Components`](https://styled-components.com/). It's a js library that combines well good-old stylesheets with inline css, and let's you style your components dynamically. You can read the docs and try it for yourself, but in your case, you would be able to have a `background` property whose value would depend on a prop (`day` or `night` for example). Try it out, you won't regret it :)

Answer (score 0):

if there is a fair amount of logic for deciding classes you can use [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames)

```
import classNames from 'classnames';

const BackgroundColor = () => {
   const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(true)

   // Define css logic
   const bgToggle = classNames({
     'background-color: black': toggle,
     'background-color: white': !toggle'
   });

   // Toggle state
   const setToogle = () => setToggle(!toggle)

   return <div onClick={setToogle} className={bgToggle}>{toggle}</div>

}
```

This is one way of doing it, there are other ways ofc

Answer (score 0):

I use [emotion's css package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@emotion/css)

```
import { css } from '@emotion/css'

const ROOT_CSS = css({
    backgroundImage: `url(${props.bgImage})`,
    backgroundColor: props.bgColor,
});
return (
    <div className={cx("overflow-auto h-full bg-repeat", ROOT_CSS)}>
    </div>
)
```